# Puppet Firewall Accepts Any Type of ICMP

Tags: puppet, firewall

I am using puppetlabs-firewall version 1.2.0 and trying to convert the iptables rules into puppet firewall. I am currently stuck on this:

```
-A custom-INPUT -m comment --comment "005 accept all icmp" -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
```

I could not find how to implement `icmp-type any`. How can I do this?

Comment: You should probably research a bit. Don't worry about the `--icmp-type` so much. Look at the README. https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-firewall it says right in there how to accept all icmp.

Comment: Agree @PeteyT, and in default puppetlabs-firewall setting  it has enable all to ICMP.

Comment: Yes, I found that statement in that readme. if that is the case, I can rest assured. I assumed the generated rule should be equivalent to above rule. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uExx9371